# MPI Error: Out of Memory - What are some solution options

Tags: c++, multicore, mpi, parallel-processing, shared-memory

I am trying to resolve [Fatal Error in MPI_Irecv: Aborting Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221058/fatal-error-in-mpi-irecv-aborting-job) and received mixed (useful, however incomplete) responses to that query.

The **error message** is the following:

```
aborting job:
> Fatal error in MPI_Irecv: Other MPI
> error, error stack: MPI_Irecv(143):
> MPI_Irecv(buf=0x8294a60, count=48,
> MPI_DOUBLE, src=2, tag=-1, 
> MPI_COMM_WORLD, request=0xffffd6ac)
> failed MPID_Irecv(64): Out of
> memory
```

***I am seeking help from someone to answer to these questions (I require guidance to help debug and resolve this deadlock)***

1. At the end of "MPI Non Blocking Send and Receive", is the memory freed by itself after the send/receive has completed OR does it have to be forced to be freed?
2. Will the issue of "Out of memory" be resolved if I use "Multiple Cores" instead of a Single one?. We presently have 4 processors to 1 core and I submit my job using the following command: `mpirun -np 4 <file>`. I tried using `mpirun n -4 <file>` but it still ran 4 threads on the same core.
3. How do I figure out how much "Shared memory" is required for my program?

The `MPI_ISend`/`MPI_IRecv` is inside a recursive loop in my code and hence not very clear if the source of error lies there (If I use the Send/Recv. commands just once or twice, system computes just fine without "Out of Memory Issues"). If so, how does one check and relieve such information?

```c
#include <mpi.h>  

#define Rows 48 

double *A = new double[Rows];
double *AA = new double[Rows];
....
....

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MPI_Status status[8]; 
    MPI_Request request[8];
    MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);   
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

    while (time < final_time){
    ...
    ...

    for (i=0; i<Columns; i++) 
    {
        for (y=0; y<Rows; y++) 
        {
            if ((my_rank) == 0)
            {
                MPI_Isend(A, Rows, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank+1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[1]);
                MPI_Irecv(AA, Rows, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank+1, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[3]);
                MPI_Wait(&request[3], &status[3]);  

                MPI_Isend(B, Rows, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank+2, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[5]);
                MPI_Irecv(BB, Rows, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank+2, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[7]);
                MPI_Wait(&request[7], &status[7]);
            }

            if ((my_rank) == 1)
            {
                MPI_Irecv(CC, Rows, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank-1, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[1]);
                MPI_Wait(&request[1], &status[1]); 
                MPI_Isend(Cmpi, Rows, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[3]);

                MPI_Isend(D, Rows, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank+2, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[6]); 
                MPI_Irecv(DD, Rows, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank+2, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[8]);
                MPI_Wait(&request[8], &status[8]);
            }

            if ((my_rank) == 2)
            {
                MPI_Isend(E, Rows, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank+1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[2]);
                MPI_Irecv(EE, Rows, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank+1, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[4]);
                MPI_Wait(&request[4], &status[4]);

                MPI_Irecv(FF, Rows, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank-2, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[5]);
                MPI_Wait(&request[5], &status[5]);
                MPI_Isend(Fmpi, Rows, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank-2, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[7]);
            }

            if ((my_rank) == 3)
            {
                MPI_Irecv(GG, Rows, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank-1, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[2]);
                MPI_Wait(&request[2], &status[2]);
                    MPI_Isend(G, Rows, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[4]);

                MPI_Irecv(HH, Rows, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank-2, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[6]);
                    MPI_Wait(&request[6], &status[6]); 
                    MPI_Isend(H, Rows, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank-2, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[8]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: using multicore instead of single one doesn't solve out of memmory issue, it's still the same ram in your computer, it doesn't matter if one core use it or 4 cores!

Comment: @Gajet: This is being run on a cluster...so I presume, each core has its own shared memory. Hence, my assumption that the memory issue could perhaps be resolved!? However, I wasnt certain and hence the idea.

Comment: 1. Reading the code isn't the issue so much; debugging it is. 2. If the error messages were anything more specific than "Out of memory" or "Other MPI error" then that assumption would probably hold true; in this case, the more info the better. 3. Editing this post with e.g. a dropbox link for those interested in debugging would be useful; another new thread is definitely not warranted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a memory leak in your program; this:

```
MPI_Isend(A, Rows, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank+1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[1]);
MPI_Irecv(AA, Rows, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank+1, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[3]);
MPI_Wait(&request[3], &status[3])
```

leaks resources associated with the `MPI_Isend` request.  You call this `Rows*Columns` times per iteration, over presumably many iterations; but you're only calling Wait for one of the requests.   You presumably need to be doing an `MPI_Waitall()` for the two requests.

But beyond that, your program is very confusing.  No sensible MPI program should have such a series of `if (rank == ...)` statements.  And since you're not doing any real work between the nonblocking send/recieves and the Waits, I don't understand why you're not just using `MPI_Sendrecv` or something.   What is your program trying to accomplish?

**UPDATE**

Ok, so it looks like you're doing standard halo-filling thing.   A few things:

1. Each task does *not* need it's own arrays - A/AA for rank 0, B/BB for rank 1, etc.  The memory is distributed, not shared; no rank can see the others arrays, so there's no need to worry about overwriting them.   (If there was, you wouldn't need to send messages).  Besides, think how much harder this makes running on different numbers of processes - you'd have to add new arrays to the code each time you changed the number of processors you use.
2. You can read/write directly into the V array rather than using copies, although the copies may be easiest to understand initially.

I've written here a little version of a halo-filling code using your variable names (`Tmyo`, `Nmyo`, `V`, indicies `i` and `y`, etc).   Each task has only it's piece of the wider V array, and exchanges its edge data with only its neighbours.   It uses characters so you can see what's going on.   It fills in its part of the V array with its rank #, and then exchanges its edge data with its neighbours.

I'd **STRONGLY** encourage you to sit down with an MPI book and work through its examples.  I'm fond of [Using MPI](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/usingmpi/), but there are many others.  There are also a lot of good MPI tutorials out there.   I think it's no exaggeration to say that 95% of MPI books and tutorials (eg, ours [here](https://support.scinet.utoronto.ca/wiki/index.php/Parallel_Scientific_Computing_-_May_2011) - see parts 5 and 6) will go through exactly this procedure as one of their first big worked examples.   They will call it halo-filling or guardcell filling or boundry exchange or something, but it all comes down to passing edge data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

char **alloc_2d_char(const int rows, const int cols) {
    char *data = (char *)malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(char));
    char **array= (char **)malloc(rows*sizeof(char*));
    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
        array[i] = &(data[cols*i]);

    return array;
}

void edgeDataFill(char **locV, const int locNmyo, const int locTmyo,
                  const int ncols, const int myrow, const int mycol,
                  const int size, const int rank) {

    MPI_Datatype leftright, updown;
    int left, right, up, down;
    int lefttag = 1, righttag = 2;
    int uptag = 3, downtag = 4;
    MPI_Status status;

    /* figure out our neighbours */
    left = rank-1;
    if (mycol == 0) left = MPI_PROC_NULL;

    right = rank+1;
    if (mycol == ncols-1) right = MPI_PROC_NULL;

    up = rank - ncols;
    if (myrow == 0) up = MPI_PROC_NULL;

    down = rank + ncols;
    if (down >= size) down = MPI_PROC_NULL;

    /* create data type for sending/receiving data left/right */
    MPI_Type_vector(locNmyo, 1, locTmyo+2, MPI_CHAR, &leftright);
    MPI_Type_commit(&leftright);

    /* create data type for sending/receiving data up/down */
    MPI_Type_contiguous(locTmyo, MPI_CHAR, &updown);
    MPI_Type_commit(&updown);

    /* Send edge data to our right neighbour, receive from left.
       We are sending the edge (locV[1][locTmyo]..locV[locNmyo][locTmyo]),
       and receiving into edge (locV[0][1]..locV[locNmyo][locTmyo]) */

    MPI_Sendrecv(&(locV[1][locTmyo]), 1, leftright, right, righttag,
                 &(locV[1][0]),       1, leftright, left, righttag,
                 MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);


    /* Send edge data to our left neighbour, receive from right.
       We are sending the edge (locV[1][1]..locV[locNmyo][1]),
       and receiving into edge (locV[1][locTmyo+1]..locV[locNmyo][locTmyo+1]) */

    MPI_Sendrecv(&(locV[1][1]),         1, leftright, left,  lefttag,
                 &(locV[1][locTmyo+1]), 1, leftright, right, lefttag,
                 MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

    /* Send edge data to our up neighbour, receive from down.
       We are sending the edge (locV[1][1]..locV[1][locTmyo]),
       and receiving into edge (locV[locNmyo+1][1]..locV[locNmyo+1][locTmyo]) */

    MPI_Sendrecv(&(locV[1][1]),         1, updown, up,   uptag,
                 &(locV[locNmyo+1][1]), 1, updown, down, uptag,
                 MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

    /* Send edge data to our down neighbour, receive from up.
       We are sending the edge (locV[locNmyo][1]..locV[locNmyo][locTmyo]),
       and receiving into edge (locV[0][1]..locV[0][locTmyo]) */

    MPI_Sendrecv(&(locV[locNmyo][1]),1, updown, down, downtag,
                 &(locV[0][1]),      1, updown, up,   downtag,
                 MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

    /* Release the resources associated with the Type_create() calls. */

    MPI_Type_free(&updown);
    MPI_Type_free(&leftright);

}

void printArrays(char **locV, const int locNmyo, const int locTmyo,
                 const int size, const int rank) {

    /* all these barriers are a terrible idea, but it's just
       for controlling output to the screen as a demo.  You'd 
       really do something smarter here... */

    for (int task=0; task<size; task++) {
        if (rank == task) {
            printf("\nTask %d's local array:\n", rank);
            for (int i=0; i<locNmyo+2; i++) {
                putc('[', stdout);
                for (int y=0; y<locTmyo+2; y++) {
                    putc(locV[i][y], stdout);
                }
                printf("]\n");
            }
        }
        fflush(stdout);
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int ierr, size, rank;
    char **locV;
    const int Nmyo=12;  /* horizontal */
    const int Tmyo=12;  /* vertical */
    const int ncols=2;  /* n procs in horizontal direction */ 
    int nrows;   
    int myrow, mycol;
    int locNmyo, locTmyo;

    ierr = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    ierr|= MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    ierr|= MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    nrows = size/ncols;
    if (nrows*ncols !=  size) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Size %d does not divide number of columns %d!\n",
                size, ncols);
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD,-1);
    }

    /* where are we? */
    mycol = rank % ncols;
    myrow = rank / ncols;

    /* figure out how many Tmyo we have */
    locTmyo  = (Tmyo / ncols);
    /* in case it doesn't divide evenly... */
    if (mycol == ncols-1) locTmyo = Tmyo - (ncols-1)*locTmyo;

    /* figure out how many Tmyo we have */
    locNmyo  = (Nmyo / nrows);
    /* in case it doesn't divide evenly... */
    if (myrow == nrows-1) locNmyo = Nmyo - (ncols-1)*locNmyo;

    /* allocate our local array, with space for edge data */
    locV = alloc_2d_char(locNmyo+2, locTmyo+2);

    /* fill in our local data - first spaces everywhere */
    for (int i=0; i<locNmyo+2; i++) 
        for (int y=0; y<locTmyo+2; y++) 
                locV[i][y] = ' ';

    /* then the inner regions have our rank # */
    for (int i=1; i<locNmyo+1; i++)
        for (int y=1; y<locTmyo+1; y++)
                locV[i][y] = '0' + rank;

    /* The "before" picture: */
    if (rank==0) printf("###BEFORE###\n");
    printArrays(locV, locNmyo, locTmyo, size, rank);

    /* Now do edge filling.  Ignore corners for now; 
       the right way to do that depends on your algorithm */

    edgeDataFill(locV, locNmyo, locTmyo, ncols, myrow, mycol, size, rank);

    /* The "after" picture: */
    if (rank==0) printf("###AFTER###\n");
    printArrays(locV, locNmyo, locTmyo, size, rank);

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

The above program can be simplified still further using `MPI_Cart_create` to create your multidimensional domain and calculate your neighbours for you automatically, but I wanted to show you the logic so you see what's going on.

Also, if you can take some advice from someone who's done this for a long time:

Any time you have line after line of repeated code: like 60 (!!) lines of this:

```
Vmax =V[i][y]-Vold; updateMaxStateChange(Vmax / dt);

mmax=m[i][y]-mold; updateMaxStateChange(mmax / dt);
hmax=h[i][y]-hold; updateMaxStateChange(hmax / dt);
jmax=j[i][y]-jold; updateMaxStateChange(jmax / dt);

mLmax=mL[i][y]-mLold; updateMaxStateChange(mLmax / dt);
hLmax=hL[i][y]-hLold; updateMaxStateChange(hLmax / dt);
hLBmax=hLB[i][y]-hLBold; updateMaxStateChange(hLBmax / dt);
hLSmax=hLS[i][y]-hLSold; updateMaxStateChange(hLSmax / dt);

amax=a[i][y]-aold; updateMaxStateChange(amax / dt);
i1fmax=i1f[i][y]-i1fold; updateMaxStateChange(i1fmax / dt);
i1smax=i1s[i][y]-i1sold; updateMaxStateChange(i1smax / dt);

Xrmax=Xr[i][y]-Xrold; updateMaxStateChange(Xrmax / dt);

i2max=i2[i][y]-i2old; updateMaxStateChange(i2max / dt);
```

that's a sign you aren't using the right data structures.   Here, you almost certainly want to have a 3d array of state variables, with (probably) the 3rd index being the species or local state variable or whatever you want to call i2, i1f, i1s, etc.   Then all these lines can be replaced with a loop, and adding a new local state variable becomes *much* simpler.

Similarly, having essentially all your state being defined as global variables is going to make your life much tougher when it comes to updating and maintaing the code.   Again, this is probably partly related to having things in zillions of independant state variables instead of having structures or higher-dimensional arrays grouping all relevant data together.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! The problem is similar to that of the "Nearest Neighbor". I have four nodes, each communicating edge array information with its nearest neighbor. So for example, Node 0 sends and receives the edge information from Nodes 1 and 3 and so on. 2. I was not sure if I could use MPI_Sendrecv for the above problem. 3. Not very clear about your comment, " No sensible MPI program should have a series of if Rank=0"..How else do you suggest I deal with this issue? Would you recommend I post my code in  its entirety? I didn't since I wasn't expecting someone thro' parse thro' all the lines.

Comment: @Jonathan: Also, Just wanted to make sure I am interpreting your comment correctly...Are you suggesting that the MPI_Sendrecv will just be a sequence of comments when I want to pass around data and not be encapsulated by If (rank == 0) type comments?

Comment: Hardcoding in the ranks like this means that if you ever want to use different number of processors, you have to completely rewrite the program.   It looks like you're doing nearest neighbour communications to do halo exchange.   Sometime tomorrow I'll try to post a simpler version of this.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.I realized that too but I wanted a functional MPI implementation before I made it more generic. Your input on this will be very useful. Thank you!

Comment: Updated with the basic structure of what you're wanting to do.   Note that the above program will work with *any* multiple of ncols processors, and it would be straightforward enough (by avoiding hardcoding ncols) to make work with any number of processors.   Also notice that once we have ncols, and once we have defined the constants for Nmyo and Tmyo, etc, we _never_ use those hardcoded numbers ever again.  This is **essential** for maintainability.

Comment: @Jonathan: Wanted some clarification on the code you had suggested particularly figuring out the neighbors. _HERE IS THE CODE_ '/* figure out our neighbours */left = rank-1;if (mycol == 0) left = MPI_PROC_NULL;right = rank+1;if (mycol == ncols-1) right = MPI_PROC_NULL; up = rank - ncols; if (myrow == 0) up = MPI_PROC_NULL;down = rank + ncols; if (down >= size) down = MPI_PROC_NULL;'. **If I assume** ncols=4, then for rank 0 (say), left = -1, right = +1, up = -4 and down = +4.  Graphically, I had earlier envisioned the 4 nodes to be on a 2x2 grid. I wasnt clear. Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: In main(), ncols is set to 2; so if you had size=4, you would have your 2 by 2 grid (`nrows = size/ncols;`), and left/right/up/down = -1/+1/-2/+2.   But of course, you could have any decomposition you want.   If you have `size` tasks, you can factor it yourself into rows/cols, or you can call `MPI_Dims_create(size, 2, dims)` to create as square a decomposition as possible, and then `rows=dims[0]; cols=dims[1];`.

Comment: Thanks! (also for sharing the links). Your website was particular useful. albeit, nothing like a hands-on session! I have been trying to assimilate and digest your suggestions. Not having a very strong background in C/C++ isnt helpful so progress has been slow. I wanted your input on two questions, 1. Based on my initial code (posted above), what was i doing incorrectly? Was the structure of how i generated dynamic arrays wrong? I am curious, just from a learning perspective, why did my code have a memory leak issue? and what would have been the simplest fix for it.

Comment: From the code, I'd say at the time you hadn't been fully comfortable with the SPMD and distributed programming model that underlies most MPI programs.   The problems with the nonblocking sends/receives + waits were really the least of the problems, and I think just came from trying to use those more advanced techniques too quickly when simpler approaches (sendrecv) would have worked just as well.   More fundamental is the hardcoding of number of processes, and having each processor use its own arrays (A/AA, B/BB, etc) which is unneccessary (and very difficult to maintain.)

Comment: The memory leak comes from the fact that each isend/irecv creates a request which requires some resources (eg, memory).   You release that memory by retiring the request, by (eg) doing a Wait() or Waitall() for *each* request.  By generating more and more requests but only calling Wait() for _some_ of them, you were only releasing _some_ of the memory, and thus you had a memory leak.

Comment: Hi Jonathan! Thanks again and appreciate your patience very much! Just fyi, I was indeed trying to replicate a 96 x 96 size sheet. So I did have each node compute a 48 x 48 sheet. Your recent comments raise two questions: 1. If I just use an A/AA for all nodes and utilize a Waitall, will this theoretically resolve the memory leak issue? Also, besides using MPI_Sendrecv, are there other commands that can help me do the guard cell filling?

Comment: Ashoman:  The memory leak issue is fixed by not leaking resources by posting nonblocking requests without waiting for them.  You can fix that by (a) waiting for _every_ request you post at some point, which you need to do for correctness anyway, and/or (b) not using nonblocking communications and using sendrecv as in the example above.   The code above is a complete and correct guard-cell filling procedure that uses no temporary arrays (eg, A/AA) at all.

Comment: Hi Jonathan: How would the usage of this syntax: MPI_Sendrecv(&A, Tmyo, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank+1, 0, &CC, Tmyo, MPI_DOUBLE, my_rank-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); be different from what you recommended, that is, you create a data type for sending and receiving data. The way I define my send_recv should be contiguous as well, correct?

Comment: Yes, if you are (needlessly) copying into and out of specially created buffers, you won't need special data types and your data will be contiguous.

Comment: Ok. I tried to set up MPI_Sendrecv and when I check on the submission status using "top", I noticed that the job gets submitted to the specified nodes but exits immediately without any errors (which it shouldn't). Two questions arise: 1. What part of setting up Sendrecv may result in such an error? 2. Could you recommend a debugger that I could use through step through the code (in MPI), line by line. Also based on your lectures, I installed IPM on the cluster. The only way to utilize/identify bottle necks is to insert the MPI comments in the code, correct?

Comment: Also, could you please provide some explanation for these lines of code, **fill in our local data - first spaces everywhere**
        'for (int i=0; i<locNmyo+2; i++) 
        for (int y=0; y<locTmyo+2; y++) 
                locV[i][y] = ' ';'

    **then the inner regions have our rank**
        for (int i=1; i<locNmyo+1; i++)
        for (int y=1; y<locTmyo+1; y++)
                locV[i][y] = '0' + rank;'
Thank you very much.

Comment: I can't possibly debug your program exiting immediatiately without errors based only on the statement that it does.  You'll need to start a new question and provide source code.   Debuggers: for small number of processors you can run one gdb per process; mpich2 has an option for this, or for openmpi, http://www.open-mpi.de/faq/?category=debugging#serial-debuggers .   Commercial solutions like ddt or totalview are great but very pricy.    IPM is a good start for profiling your MPI code, but the first step is to get things working correctly; performance is a second-order consideration.

Comment: As to initialization, it does exactly what it seems to - locV is a char array for simplicity in printing output so you can see what's going on.  Hopefully you ran the program to see what's going on.  You fill the whole thing with spaces (including the edges that you'll get from your neighbours) to initialize things, and then you fill the internal region (not the edges you're getting from your neighbours) with data that identifies the rank it was filled by -- just the character representation of the rank number.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! I did run your source code and submitted it using mpirun -np XX filename.cpp. I noticed the following: When XX = 4 processors, your source code generates a 6x6 matrix for each rank and then the "After" is edge populated with the neighbor's rank. Which is fine. When I increase XX to 6, I notice something strange (i.e., which I cannot comprehend just looking at the results)...each rank now has a matrix of 6x4 (ranks 0, 1, 2, 3) and ranks 4 and 5 have a matrix of 6x8?

Comment: Maybe - this might just be me misunderstanding what you were trying to do.  I assumed there was one Nmyo x Tmyo sized array that you were distributing across processors.  (Note that the way I'm doing this partitioning is the simplest way, good for small examples but not necessarily the way that is the closest to divide evenly; there are better ways to do it so things come out a little more evenly.  But if your grid is big enough, these discretess issues become less and less important).

Comment: On the other hand, if you want your local grid to be the same size for each processor and the global grid should change with the number of processors, then you'd do it differently.  Or if there were other constraints (you want each processor to have the same size domain, but the size itself can vary), you'd have to implement that.  If you're doing the usual 2d-pde-on-a-grid thing, then the way I have it above is the usual way of doing it (plus or minus little refinements).

Comment: Thank you for responding. Nmyo and Tmyo are variables that define the number of "cells" in each dimension. So say in the case where -np XX=4, I wanted each processor to run Nmyo X Tmyo 2D sheet. In the case of 4 processors, I wanted the edges to communicate. That is all. I ran into issues doing MPI_Isend. I chose that since I felt, I could save processor time. At this point, my focus is getting to run MPI to communicate over several time steps. I was able to succeed in doing a static edge array transfer (like your example above, although hard coded only for 4 processors) and later for the big.

Comment: I had initially assumed that your code would keep the local grid the same but be able to scale based on the change in the global grid. As suggested by you, I will start an alternate thread to show you what I tried with the MPI_Sendrecv. If you could just help me identify what I am doing incorrectly. That will help me move to atleast start profiling my code and working on improving it. I looked for local resources to help (including using MPI) but it just hasn't worked for me as yet. Thank you- Ashwin

Comment: I have started a new thread for the MPI_Sendrecv issue. Here is the link to the question: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445234/issue-with-mpi-sendrecv>

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the library, but...
1) You should not delete the buffer after the read. You have allocated the buffer (dynamically) at program startup. As long as you delete it (once) at termination, you should be fine. Actually, even if you don't delete it, it should get cleaned up when the program exits (but that's sloppy).

2) Multiple cores should have no effect on a memory problem.

3) Not sure. MPI should have some documentation to help you.

Comment: Thanks John! Could you please clarify what you mean by "Deleting the buffer at termination".

Comment: John, I had tried what you recommended and was unsuccessful? Is there something else I can try?